# Bar chart not showing all categories Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I am fairly new to creating charts in jasper but i'm at my wits end with this issue.

I have a data set that is returning proper data that is set up like so

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| qtr        url_txt  user_role_txt  page_cnt |
+---------------------------------------------+
| Quarter 1 some url1 some role1     154      |
| Quarter 1 some url2 some role2     11       |
| Quarter 2 some url1 some role2     12       |
| Quarter 3 some url2 some role1     110      |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

But every iteration I have tried has failed so I tried another way to get this table (also returning correct data)

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| qtr       url_txt role1_page role2_page |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Quarter 1 some url   1154        11     |
| Quarter 1 some url2   0         12      |
| Quarter 2 some url1   12          11    |
| Quarter 3 some url2s   11           0   |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

something similar and this got closer with getting the correct numbers but not the right quarters showing on the chart.

Only reason I am showing both versions of the data is because possibly the old version was better for this issue.

Here is how it was

[image: Previous Iteration]

Here is how it is now

[image: Current Iteration]

In both instances, only 2 quarters tend to show up no matter the date range I choose (bottom one is one month off from the first picture)

it is usually showing  a single quarter but every now and then I get quarter 1 and quarter 4 but there is obviously data in quarter 2 and 3 from when I run the query in the sql.

Here is the jrxml of the latest version

Any help would be amazing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1 -->
<!-- 2018-08-21T14:23:03 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="usg_rpt_bar"
              pageWidth="576" pageHeight="792"
              whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"
              columnWidth="536" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20"
              isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" 
              uuid="c90df0e9-ca70-4aa8-88ab-3cc66cad2ade">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (2)"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="inch"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="false"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="7d5280b5-f2f1-4d32-9729-2bb222a23169">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>

        </queryString>
    </subDataset>

    <parameter name="START_DATE" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="END_DATE" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="START_DATE_RPT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="END_DATE_RPT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SCREENS" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <parameter name="Q1START" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q1END" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q2START" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q2END" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q3START" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q3END" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q4START" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q4END" class="java.util.Date"/>

    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT DISTINCT ON (url_txt)
t.qtr as qtr,
t.url_txt as url_txt,
sum(t.pub) as pub_page,
sum(t.itm) as itm_page,
sum(t.cms) as cms_page,
sum(t.gst) as gst_page,
sum(t.lib) as lib_page
from
(
SELECT
'Quarter 1' as qtr,
url_txt,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Item Developers' then 1 else 0 end as itm,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Public' then 1 else 0 end as pub,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Librarian' then 1 else 0 end as lib,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'GST' then 1 else 0 end as gst,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'CMS' then 1 else 0 end as cms

from db.table

where acs_ts::date >= $P{Q1START}
AND acs_ts::date <= $P{Q1END}
AND $X{IN,url_txt,SCREENS}

UNION ALL

SELECT
'Quarter 2' as qtr,
url_txt,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Item Developers' then 1 else 0 end as itm,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Public' then 1 else 0 end as pub,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Librarian' then 1 else 0 end as lib,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'GST' then 1 else 0 end as gst,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'CMS' then 1 else 0 end as cms

from db.table

where acs_ts::date >= $P{Q2START}
AND acs_ts::date <= $P{Q2END}
AND $X{IN,url_txt,SCREENS}

UNION ALL

SELECT
'Quarter 3' as qtr,
url_txt,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Item Developers' then 1 else 0 end as itm,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Public' then 1 else 0 end as pub,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Librarian' then 1 else 0 end as lib,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'GST' then 1 else 0 end as gst,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'CMS' then 1 else 0 end as cms

from db.table

where acs_ts::date >= $P{Q3START}
AND acs_ts::date <= $P{Q3END}
AND $X{IN,url_txt,SCREENS}

UNION ALL

SELECT
'Quarter 4' as qtr,
url_txt,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Item Developers' then 1 else 0 end as itm,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Public' then 1 else 0 end as pub,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'Librarian' then 1 else 0 end as lib,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'GST' then 1 else 0 end as gst,
CASE when user_role_txt = 'CMS' then 1 else 0 end as cms

from db.table

where acs_ts::date >= $P{Q4START}
AND acs_ts::date <= $P{Q4END}
AND $X{IN,url_txt,SCREENS}

) as t

group by t.qtr, t.url_txt]]>

    </queryString>

    <field name="url_txt" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="qtr" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="itm_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="cms_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="gst_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="pub_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="lib_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>

    <sortField name="qtr"/>

    <group name="Group1" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{url_txt}]]>
        </groupExpression>
    </group>

    <pageHeader>
        <band height="98" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="t_4" mode="Opaque"
                               x="130" y="-1" width="320" height="15"
                               isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"
                               forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"
                               uuid="70d07b08-a98f-462f-912c-86e8ca3cffa5">

                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h1"
                              value="full"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>

                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DEL Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="([GENERAL])" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="COMPUTE_5" mode="Opaque"
                               x="140" y="15" width="300" height="15"
                               forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"
                               uuid="fa243ebd-82b3-426a-8693-995a1d029d8c">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h1"
                              value="full"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA["Data Element Library Usage Report"]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="DATE_1" mode="Opaque"
                               x="430" y="0" width="102" height="12"
                               forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"
                               uuid="8c30e5fd-4921-4b61-a07d-fec225f73dca">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2"
                              value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h3"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA["Run Date: " + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date())]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="PAGE_1" mode="Opaque"
                               x="430" y="12" width="40" height="12"
                               forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"
                               uuid="d3278171-f2e1-4241-b57f-5e4f3fc2ee09">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2"
                              value="start"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h3"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " of "]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="PAGE_1" mode="Transparent"
                               x="470" y="12" width="30" height="12"
                               forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"
                               uuid="f12aa9ee-4dbb-4569-bad4-1994dcfc045c">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h3"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2"
                              value="end"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="56"
                               uuid="5c21389e-0147-4bab-8b2b-b2462883c4e4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width"
                              value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height"
                              value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{CMSLOGO_DIR} + "CMS_logo.jpg"]]>
                </imageExpression>
                <hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
                    <![CDATA["Centers for Medicare & Medicaid Services"]]>
                </hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="280" height="12"
                               uuid="9f93ebb5-6ca9-4f7f-be7c-d06093207859">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h3"
                              value="start"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height"
                              value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Note: * indicates an empty value.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="30" width="300" height="20"
                               uuid="c2b0287c-ce1e-461c-aabb-1c6e28b0b30d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA["From "+$P{START_DATE_RPT}+" to "+$P{END_DATE_RPT}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="285">
            <barChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="true">
                    <reportElement key="" x="0" y="40" width="532" height="245"
                                   uuid="090b7b3c-b745-45bd-af08-3b79a027f3c6">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="inch"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <chartTitle position="Top">
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA[$F{url_txt}]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend position="Right"/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset resetType="Page"/>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Public"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{pub_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["CMS"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{cms_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["GST"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{gst_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Librarian"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{lib_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Item Developers"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{itm_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot backgroundAlpha="1.0"/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Quarter"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Page Count"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Edit: I have been in the same position and found that changing the select distinct on changes how the graph interacts, I have yet to find a proper way to finish this still. This has been the only combination that even gets multiple quarters, all other attempts made a new chart for each quarter and each role.